# Zend_Paginator Without DbSelect/DbTableSelect adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

Is there a way to use Zend_Paginator Without DbSelect/DbTableSelect adapter without having to fetch whole data set?

I have 2000 objects I want to paginate with Zend_Paginator but I cannot use DbSelect/DbTableSelect for a certain reason.

Is there a way to to this? I could use array for example but that would load all 2000 objects at every page.

Comment: Zend_Paganiator has adapters other than DbSelect/DbTableSelect adapter. You could have a look at Array or Iterator adapters.

Comment: @Marcin I know. But according to the documentation those adapters load the entire dataset which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the bast way to achieve that is writing your own adapter which will implement `Zend_Paginator_Interface` (which implements `Countable`). Then you can hide all your logic behind that adapter and use `Zend_Paginator` as always.

Couple paragraphs about custom sources: [Zend_Paginator advanced usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.advanced.html).